# railsアプリでのぐるなびAPIについて（linebot）

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在railsのlinebotでぐるなびapiを呼び出して利用しようと考えています。

ぐるなびapiの他にopen_weatherのapiも利用しており、リンクで取得したデータを `curl -X GET` で文字列として取得できたのですが、同じ記述ではぐるなびapiから文字列でデータを取得することができません。
どのような記述で呼び出すことができるのか教えていただければ幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**Railsの記述**
[image: railsの記述です]

Comment: https://api.gnavi.co.jp/api/manual/restsearch/ を見ますと、クエリパラメータ `address` の備考欄に「（都道府県＋市町村＋番地）の文字列をUTF-8でURLエンコードすること」と書かれています。質問欄の画像では `area` という変数がこれに当たると思われますが、フォーマットは「都道府県＋市町村＋番地)になっているでしょうか？ また、URLエンコードをしていますでしょうか？

Comment: 「取得できない」とは具体的にどんな状況なのか、例えばエラーが表示されるならその内容も含めて質問に追記しておくとアドバイスも付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: metropolisさん　返信ありがとうございます。一応今の記述でcurl -Xを取り除くとリンクの中に問題なくぐるなびの情報が呼び出せるようになっている状況です。open_weatherではその状況からcurl -Xの記述を足しただけで文字列として取得できたので何か記述の部分で問題があるのではと考えた次第です

Comment: cubick♦さん　アドバイスありがとうございます。写真追加いたしました

Comment: 「絞り込み条件を指定して下さい」というメッセージが適切だとすれば、`lunch` とか `no_smoking` といったクエリパラメータも指定する必要がありそうです。ただ、APIテーブルには絞り込み条件が必須とは書かれていないのが気になりますが…